# Double file /etc/passwd in debian

Tags: debian, shadow, passwd

in my server (Debian) I have a copy of this file

```
/etc/passwd
/etc/passwd-
/etc/shadow
/etc/shadow-
/etc/group
/etc/group-
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

The files with the dash (-) at the end are backups. I would diff the files and see what changed. Investigate from there.